# luajit '=' expected near '-'

Tags: lua, luajit

I have been trying to use luajit to compile luas, which is not relevant right now.
However, when I try to enter `luajit -h` (which should usually list commands) into the cmd looking luajit.exe window, I get the error " '=' expected near '-' ".

I have tried everything, including building the program using visual studio (msvcbuild into visual studio console) but nothing has worked so far and I am just devastated.

This error seems so easy to fix, yet is just a nightmare for someone who doesn't code at all.

Comment: It sounds like you're opening luajit and typing `luajit -h` as Lua code. `luajit` is a shell command, so you'll need to open a terminal for that. (I don't know how to do that on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

The error you are facing is a Lua error. To Lua `luajit -h` doesn't make sense.

-h is a [command line option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option) It is appended to a command. In that case running luajit with the -h option will print the available command line options to your terminal console.

You can create a shortcut to luajit with that option or run luajit from your command line.

Start Window's command line interpreter `cmd.exe` and enter `luajit -h`. (assuming your `luajit.exe` is in `PATH` or you're already in the directory containing luajit.exe